# CSS Highlight list entries

Tags: html, css

I've created a simple list as follows :

```css
.menu ul {
  font-size:20px;
  margin-left:0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left:5px;

}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3em;
  margin: 0.45em 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-size:20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:hover {
  color: #2693ff;
}

.menu li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.1em;
  left: 0.9em;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% - 2em);
  content: '';
  z-index: 0;
}

.menu li li {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Learn HTML</li>
      <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Create my own web site:
        <ol>
          <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Development Articles</li>
          <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>News and Stuff</li>
          <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Funny Cat Pictures</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>PROFIT</li>
      <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>PROFIT
      <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Create my own web site:
        <ol>
          <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Development Articles</li>
          <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>News and Stuff</li>
          <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Funny Cat Pictures</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="menu"><span class="icon-indent"></span>Funny Cat Pictures</li>
    </ul>
```

Using CSS I can highlight each entry as I hover over it.

However if I hover over the main entry of a nested list or an individual entry within the nested list, all entries within that nested level are highlighted along with it's main entry.

Is there any way to do this so only the entry I'm hovering over is highlighted and not all entries with in the nested list?

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/hba5jgxb/)** showing the issue

Comment: Just put your menu entries' content inside `<a>` or `<span>` tags, and add `:hover` styles only to those instead of `li`. Aside, why are you using different quote characters (single quotes on `ul` and  `li`, double quotes on your `span` elements)?

Comment: besides u have already got the answers form others, u have an html error in the 11th line. u forgot the closing </li> tag. so `<li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> PROFIT ` should be `<li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> PROFIT  </li>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/hba5jgxb/1/

Wrap the text of each item in a tag, then apply CSS hover for it:

```
<li class='menu'>
  <span class="icon-indent"></span>
  <span class="item-text">Learn HTML</span>
</li>

.item-text:hover {
  color: #2693ff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that sorted it :)

Answer (score 4):

Set color black on menu li. See if this helps.

```
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3em;
    margin: 0.45em 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1.8em;
        font-size:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     color: #000000; <-- ADD THIS
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2t3cqr5m/

Comment: Thanks I like the affect this has.

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```css
.menu ul {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 3em;
  margin: 0.45em 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
ul > li:hover {
  color: #2693ff;
}
ol > li:hover {
  color: #2693ff;
}
.menu li:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.1em;
  left: 0.9em;
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% - 2em);
  content: '';
  z-index: 0;
}
.menu li li {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Learn HTML</li>
  <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Create my own web site:</li>
  <ol>
    <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Development Articles</li>
    <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> News and Stuff</li>
    <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Funny Cat Pictures</li>
  </ol>

  <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> PROFIT</li>
  <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> PROFIT
    <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Create my own web site:</li>
      <ol>
        <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Development Articles</li>
        <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> News and Stuff</li>
        <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Funny Cat Pictures</li>
      </ol>
    
    <li class='menu'><span class="icon-indent"></span> Funny Cat Pictures</li>
</ul>
```